# tm t1 has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, unix, time.h

I have to write a program that calls `sleep(60)` in an infinite loop. Every five times through the loop I have to fetch the current time-of-day and print the tm_sec field.

This is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm t1;
    int i=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        sleep(60);
        if(i%5==0)
            {
                gettimeofday(&t1,NULL);
                printf("%d\n",t1.tm_sec);
            }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error saying `aggregate tm t1 has incomplete type and cannot be defined.`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You want struct timeval, not struct tm.  Try this:

```
struct timeval t1;
```

Also, you want `t1.tv_sec`, not `t1.tm_sec`.

Comment: I have to print the tm_sec field, which is not defined in the structure timeval.

Comment: Then look at Kerrek's answer.

Comment: That will make the code compile, but it won't give the same output as printing the `tm_sec` field.

Answer (score 2):

You're using it wrong. Pick one of the following two:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
int settimeofday(const struct timeval *tv, const struct timezone *tz);
```

Or:

```
 #include <time.h>

 char *asctime(const struct tm *tm);
 struct tm *gmtime(const time_t *timep);
 struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
```

Comment: You'll have to pick both in order to get the local time (with `time()` or `gettimeofday()`), *and* convert into a `tm` to get the `tm_sec` field.

Comment: You mean the microseconds? `time()` is already precise to the second, non? I thought `gettimeofday` completely subsumes `time`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: no, I mean you need *both* something to get the current time *and* something to structure it into a `tm`. Your answer says to pick one of those things - how would you solve the problem without both? Or is calling `time()` supposed to be implied by your answer?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Ah, of course, you need `time()` *or* the seconds part of `gettimeofday` to get the actual time which `gmtime` can then process. I was a bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

`gettimeofday` takes a pointer to `timeval`, not `tm`, giving the time as seconds (and microseconds) since 1970.

If you want a `tm`, then you'll need the functions from `<ctime>`, such as `localtime()`, to convert the seconds field of the `timeval`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to compile `m_wifi.h` on my [ESP32 libraries](https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries#readme).

This is the C++ compiler issue that may not configure properly.If `time.h` was included in your code or in the library and you get this compilation error.

On my case, the `tm` structure was already declared in `time.h`. In sum, all I had to do, was to remove the library I had included, the `time.h`, and leave the ESP32 version `ESP32Time.h`

I also had to correct the code from `struct tm timeinfo` to `tm timeinfo` on the variable declartion section.